# Populatate the spinner from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseReference reference;
Spinner areaSpinner;
ArrayList<String> areas = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://vbspinner.firebaseio.com/Location");

    areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    DatabaseReference mref = reference.child("areas");

    FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
            ((TextView)findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(model);

        }
    };
    areaSpinner.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
}
```

My Firebase database:

[image: 1]

My constructor class code is

```
public class VBSpinner extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if(!com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()){
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        }
```

I would like that my spinner values are from the Firebase database (`Kvp`, `Tn`,`Tvl`, so on). Where do I need to change the data?

Comment: Whats the result of first code sample? That might work. Did you encounter any error or exceptions? Or the spinner simply not showing any options?

Comment: no error but app shows spinner without options

Comment: your `reference ` is pointing to `https://vbspinner.firebaseio.com/Location`. And `mref` is pointing at `reference.child("areas")` therefor, you are reading `https://vbspinner.firebaseio.com/Location/areas` to be placed into your spinner. Of course it will have no value

Comment: thank you Koceeng, now its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
     .getReferenceFromUrl("https://vbspinner.firebaseio.com/Location");
```

In above code, you make `reference` object point to `"Location"` (which I think what you're trying to do. But in the following code:

```
DatabaseReference mref = reference.child("areas");
```

You make another reference called `mref` that (because of `child("areas")`) point to `"https://vbspinner.firebaseio.com/Location/areas"`. So if you use `mref` in your `FirebaseListAdapter`, it will return null because there is no value in `".../Location/areas"`.

You should use `reference` in `FirebaseListAdapter` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am quite late to answer but try my method to parse firebase document items into spinner adapter

https://gist.github.com/majeytunio/9cc24a7edb06b2c2d3bbbb649ac9b602

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes