# How can I populate a spinner with my Firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-spinner

I want to populate a spinner instead of a ListView with data from Firebase.
The code below works fine with ListView. But how can I replace the ListView with a spinner? Hope someone can help me with this.

My research:
[Firebase data to Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210718/firebase-data-to-spinner)

[Populatate the spinner from Firebase database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42480718/populatate-the-spinner-from-firebase-database)

Here is my Main Activity:

```
public class Ansattliste extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databaseAnsatt;
ListView lvansattliste;
Button btnleggtilansatt;

List<Ansatt> listansatt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ansattliste);

    databaseAnsatt = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ansatte");

    lvansattliste = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvansattliste);
    listansatt = new ArrayList<>();

    btnleggtilansatt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnleggtilansatt);
    btnleggtilansatt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent leggtil = new Intent(Ansattliste.this, Leggtilansatt.class);
            startActivity(leggtil);

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseAnsatt.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            listansatt.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot ansattSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                final Ansatt ansatt = ansattSnapshot.getValue(Ansatt.class);
                listansatt.add(ansatt);
                final listAnsatt adapter = new listAnsatt(Ansattliste.this, listansatt);
                lvansattliste.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (DatabaseError databaseError){
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my Adapter:

```
public class listAnsatt extends ArrayAdapter<Ansatt> {

private Activity context;
private List<Ansatt> listansatt;


public listAnsatt(Activity context, List<Ansatt> listansatt) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_ansatt, listansatt);
    this.context = context;
    this.listansatt = listansatt;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();


    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_ansatt, null, true);

    TextView tvansattnavn = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvansattnavn);
    TextView tvansaattnr = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.tvansattnr);

    Ansatt ansatt = listansatt.get(position);
    tvansattnavn.setText(ansatt.getAnsattnavn());
    tvansaattnr.setText(ansatt.getAnsattnr());

    return listViewItem;
}
```

Firebase:
[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWsb0.png)

Comment: Have you tried to implement a spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do something like following (I've adapted from Kotlin code I have here so possibility of some syntax errors)...have assumed for illustration that `getAnsattnavn()` is value you want to show in spinner.  You'd still have `listansatt` which presumably you'd look up when item is selected in spinner.

In `onDataChange`:

```
    List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot ansattSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        final Ansatt ansatt = ansattSnapshot.getValue(Ansatt.class);
        optionList.add(ansatt.getAnsattnavn());
        listansatt.add(ansatt);
    } 

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, optionList);
    spinnerControl.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: he is using a custom adapter

Comment: So I can't use this method above when I'm using a custom adapter?

Comment: You should be able to do something very similar when using custom adapter.  Just to confirm why you need custom adapter....you're not showing just list of options in the spinner?

Comment: I manage to do it like you showed me. Thank you John :) I use the spinner to show me a list of options to choose from.

Comment: But I need to do this in my alertdialog, now I have just tested it in my mainactivity. So in a different activity I have a private void showupdatedialog and a private boolean. Where should I use the code you suggested?

Comment: @Alexander I'd suggest moving your firebase query code out of any UI classes and put in some kind of shared Repository class which you can then access in different places in UI (potentially injecting using something like `Dagger`).....UI code would subscribe to update which would be list of `Ansatt` objects.

Comment: @John I'm a beginner at java, so can you maybe explain some more? My issue is that I have two database: One with tools, and one with Employees. That I want to do is when I press on a listview item in tools I get an alertdialog with an option (spinner) with the data from the Employees database. I get everything to function now, except that my tools (database) listeview won't update. Before this I just had a spinner with entries from strings (and that worked). But now I want to have all the employees in a database, so it is easy to add more later. Do you understand me? :)

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work :) Thank you for the help @JohnO'Reilly